# vim -s in command line without opening vim

Tags: vim

I run vim scripts on a regular base. Is it possible to run a script e.g.
`vim -s script.vim file.txt` without opening vim and returning possible error messages to the terminal?

Comment: How do you expect Vim to run your script without being opened?

Comment: Could have been that there is something like a headless/background/hidden/silent mode in which the job is processed and vim then reports back when the job is done. 
I'm currently on a Windows machine and was thinking some kind of
`vim -s script.vim file.txt &` (untested) for a linux machine.

Comment: Run [`ex`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#ex) or use [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) or [`awk`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)